# Plotting multiple datasets with plotly.express geo_scatter

Tags: python, plotly-python, satellite-image

I am currently trying to model an orbiting satellite using scatter_geo. I can model currently the flight path around the Earth fine. My issue is, unlike matplotlib, I cant seem to make a subplot usng the figure property. Ive been looking through the plotly.express documentation but I couldnt seem to find a work around. My code so far is...

```
fig = px.scatter_geo(prop_data['2022-06-06':'2022-06-06'],
               animation_frame='hour',
               color='visible',
               lat='latitude',
               lon='longitude',
               opacity=0.3,
               hover_data=['elevation', 'azimuth'],
           projection='orthographic',)


fig.show()
```

and this produces the plot

Picture of satellite plot with visibility included
[image: Picture of satellite plot with visibility included]

As you can see, the plot indicates when the satellite is within the field of view of the station, but you cannot physically see where the station is. Ive tried to use the property 'location' specified in the documentation of scatter_geo but it ended up overwriting my data. Ive tried also to use the figure property but unfortunately that is only a property of matplotlib. Ive also tried 'hold on' to try and add another subplot but that didnt work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!